Precise reference for Helmholtz decomposition
I am looking for a precise discussion of the Helmholtz decomposition. The usual statement I was able to find is something along the line

If $\vec{v}$ is a smooth vector field vanishing at infinity, then it
can be written as $\vec{v}=\mathrm{grad}\varphi+\vec{w}$ where
$\varphi$ is a smooth function and $\vec{w}$ a divergence-free smooth
vector field. Furthermore, $\varphi$ and $\vec{w}$ can be chosen to
vanish at infinity and the splitting is unique with this assumption.

But clearly, there is something missing in this statement. The usual approach to prove the theorem is by defining $\varphi$ as the unique solution of the Poisson equation $\mathrm{div}(\vec{v})=\Delta\varphi$. Now, it is well-known that the Poisson equation has a unique solution vanishing at infinity for any source vanishing at infinity. However, in general, it is not true that $\mathrm{div}(\vec{v})$ vanishes at infinity even when $\vec{v}$ does. So, it seems that one also needs to assume that $\partial_{i}\vec{v}$ vanishes at infinity.
Does anyone have a precise reference?

An interesting answer here.
